# How to limit the pulling distance with a refresh control?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm trying to loading some data in a `UITableView` using a `UIRefreshControl`. I did,

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    // Get the current size of the refresh controller
    CGRect refreshBounds = refreshControl.bounds;

    // Distance the table has been pulled >= 0
    CGFloat pullDistance = MAX(0.0, -self.newsTableView.contentOffset.y);

    // Half the width of the table
    CGFloat midX = self.newsTableView.frame.size.width / 2.0;

    CGFloat spinnerHeight = self.compass_spinner.bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat spinnerHeightHalf = spinnerHeight / 2.0;

    CGFloat spinnerWidth = self.compass_spinner.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat spinnerWidthHalf = spinnerWidth / 2.0;

    // Set the Y coord of the graphics, based on pull distance
    CGFloat spinnerY = pullDistance / 2.0 - spinnerHeightHalf;

    // Calculate the X coord of the graphics, adjust based on pull ratio
    CGFloat spinnerX = (midX - spinnerWidthHalf);

    // When the compass and spinner overlap, keep them together
    self.isRefreshIconsOverlap = YES;

    // If the graphics have overlapped or we are refreshing, keep them together
    if (self.isRefreshIconsOverlap || refreshControl.isRefreshing) {
        spinnerX = midX - spinnerWidthHalf;
    }

    CGRect spinnerFrame = self.compass_spinner.frame;
    spinnerFrame.origin.x = spinnerX;
    spinnerFrame.origin.y = spinnerY;

    self.compass_spinner.frame = spinnerFrame;

    // Set the encompassing view's frames
    refreshBounds.size.height = pullDistance;

    self.refreshColorView.frame = refreshBounds;
    self.refreshLoadingView.frame = refreshBounds;

    // If we're refreshing and the animation is not playing, then play the animation
    if (refreshControl.isRefreshing && !self.isRefreshAnimating) {
        [self animateRefreshView];
    }
}
```

using this code I can pull down the table view to bottom of the screen. My UIRefresControl like

```
 // Initialize Refresh Control
refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 20)];

// Configure Refresh Control
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

To refresh using this, I need to drag like 1/2 of the screen. How may I refresh this in a short drag(pull)?

Comment: Why are you doing all of this? If you use a standard `UITableViewController`, adding support for "pull-to-refresh" is just 3 simple lines of code in `viewDidLoad` to setup the `UIRefreshControl`. No need for any code in the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To shorten the pull distance of **`UIRefreshControl`** you can try this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -110 && ![refreshControl isRefreshing]) {
        [refreshControl beginRefreshing];
        //your code for refresh
        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good quick solution for the problem, you still have issues like not finishing the slow pull animation, but short of something custom, this does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are experiencing this problem because you set up your refresh control in a wrong way. Don't `init` your refresh control with frame. just do `[[alloc] init]` or `[new]` and put it as a background view of table view. Table view knows how to handle it.

```
self.myRefreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
[self.myRefreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.myTableView setBackgroundView:self.myRefreshControl];
```

This is how you usually set up a pull to refresh control. But if this still doesn't satisfy you you can either subclass `UIRefreshControl` which is absolutely not an optimal solution for that case or you can just trick things in UIScrollView Delegate methods as [tnylee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2053537) suggests. But doing customizing default behavior in `scrollViewDidScroll` is not a wise decision.

Comment: for setBackgroundView it solved my problem in other way